# Add multiple Pins to Xamarin.Maps in MVVM

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maps

I am having issues trying to understand how to add Pins to a map in MVVM pattern. (I can have multiple maps in the view).

Here's my ViewModel Code.

```
<flv:FlowListView SeparatorVisibility="Default" HasUnevenRows="True" FlowItemTappedCommand="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}" FlowLastTappedItem="{Binding LastTappedItem}" FlowColumnMinWidth="600" FlowItemsSource="{Binding DashboardWidgets}" >
    <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Margin="1">
                    <!--Map Widgets -->
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{Binding bgcolor}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" IsVisible="False" >
                        <StackLayout.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding resultsettype}" Value="map">
                                <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </StackLayout.Triggers>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  Padding="4" HeightRequest="400" WidthRequest="600">
                            <maps:Map x:Name="MyMap" IsShowingUser="true" MapType="Hybrid" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <!--Image Widgets -->
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{Binding bgcolor}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="600" Padding="4" IsVisible="False">
                        <StackLayout.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding resultsettype}" Value="image">
                                <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </StackLayout.Triggers>
                        <StackLayout Padding="1" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="600">
                            <Image Source="{Binding contentvalue, Converter={StaticResource LocalBase64ToImageConverter}}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
    </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
```

I have an Observable collection of DashboardWidgets which can hold a map, image, integer or a list. 
If it's a map, I will get all the pins in VM and somehow bind them to the map. Since I am using mvvm pattern, I shouldnot access the Map in my VM and moreover I have no clue how to do it either.

So I far have tried Extending the Map to make pins bindable but to no success.

```
public class ExtendedMap : Map
    {
     public static readonly BindableProperty PinsProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MultiPins), typeof(IList<Pin>), typeof(ExtendedMap), new List<Pin>());
     public List<Pin> MultiPins
         {
            get {
                        var val = (List<Pin>)GetValue(PinsProperty);
                        return new List<Pin>();
                         }
                    set => SetValue(PinsProperty, value);
                    }                
                }      
        }
```

I tried creating a contentview binding it's content to property inside vm but no luck.

XAML: 
    Tried both. None worked.

```
<contentview content={binding widgetResult } />
<contentview content={binding mapresult} />
```

VM:
    VM implements IPropertyChanged.

```
var map = new Map(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(37, -122), Distance.FromMiles(0.3)))
                {
                IsShowingUser = true,
                HeightRequest = 100,
                WidthRequest = 960,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
                };
        (await GetMapPins(widget.filter)).ForEach(f => map.Pins.Add(f));
        widget.widgetResult = new ContentView
                {
                    Content = map
                 };
        widget.mapresult = map;
```

Comment: MVVM does not necessarily mean doing everything with bindings. You can do View work in code, that is why there is a C# code behind file for every View. So you can keep the data for your Maps and pins in the View Model, but then min the View's C# code you can get the Map/Pin data from the ViewModel and in code, add the Maps/pins to the UI as needed. This is not a violation of MVVM pattern IMO. Some things are just easier to do, and understand, in code rather than setting up complex bindings.

Comment: @jgoldberger-MSFT I agree with you.  I have tried setting a content view in the view and adding the content from the viewmodel. I might be doing something wrong, it just didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is in error:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty PinsProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MultiPins), typeof(IList<Pin>), typeof(ExtendedMap), new List<Pin>());

public List<Pin> MultiPins {...}
```

The name of the BindableProperty MUST be the name of the property itself, in this case "MultiPins", plus "Property", so the BindableProperty name MUST be "MultiPinsProperty", e.g.:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty MultiPinsProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MultiPins), typeof(IList<Pin>), typeof(ExtendedMap), new List<Pin>());

public List<Pin> MultiPins {...}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties#creating-a-property

> The naming convention for bindable properties is that the bindable property identifier must match the property name specified in the Create method, with "Property" appended to it.